# Publishing corporate app in App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I am developing corporate mobile app and I want to publish it in App Store - so that all employees that work in specific company can download this it.

As this app is for corporate use - only people that have an account granted by HR manager will be able to login and use this app. There will be no option to register from app.

I know that there is Enterprise Program from Apple but I want to know -

1) Is it possible to publish this kind of app to the App Store as a regular member of Apple Developer Program?

2) Are there any restrictions that I should to take in consideration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple's [App Store guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/), it is **not permitted** to publish an app which only selected people can use.

Your only choices are [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/), [the Apple Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) and [the Apple B2B Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/).

Comment: There’s also the b2b App Store program.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Thanks for the addition, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No your app will only be available as private distribution as b2b app. There is no restriction as I know. I have one app that work similarly as other app but the only difference is that it is not available in AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

No difference as per feature level.

Its licenses is costly but you will receive code level technical support.

Read more:
https://leolearning.com/2012/11/apple-developer-vs-apple-enterprise-licenses/

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link for corporate app in App Store development:
    https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html